# Receiving emails on a server different to the host

Tags: asp.net, email, hosting, dns

my client and I need to get him receiving emails this week.

The domain register company is in holland and we've pointed the nameservers to our server in New Zealand. The website is hosted on the new zealand server and is running fine. But we are going to move the website to the dutch company sometime in the next month or so (for better SEO as the people viewing it are from Europe).

Client needs to start receiving emails ASAP, is it possible to receive emails on the dutch host (that we will move to) now, whilst still hosting the website on the new zealand website? Or should we just host emails from NZ and then switch both web and email over in a month or so.

Comment: Offtopic for this site, but yes, it's possible. Set your domain's MX record to point to the dutch server, while the main A records point to your NZ servers. MX record defines where mail delivery attempts should be made, and do NOT have to be the same as the main A records.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Marc. You can set your MX record on your Control Panel and point it to Dutch server. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your email now by simple change the dns file. In the dns file there is a line that point to the mail server, there you just change the ip to the new mail server, and all mails go to the new server.

I hope that you have setup your users mail to look at the mail server name (eg mail.host.com) and not on the www.host.com or just host.com. If you do not have done that, ask them to change  the mail server on their mail software to the correct name.